# Sequencer's OpenGL render crashes with Grease Pencil

Tags: rendering, animation, video-sequence-editor, opengl, grease-pencil

I am trying to render a sequence in the sequencer.

I want to add a scene strip and render an openGL animation (with the grease pencil), hence I have grease pencil strokes in the 3D view.

Pressing the sequencer openGL render button crashes Blender. (This doesn't happen when I remove all grease pencil items.)

Tested in 2.78c and 2.77.

(How) can I use the sequencer's openGL render with grease pencil animation?

(Bug or Feature-ish?)

[image]

I have found [this bugtracker post](https://developer.blender.org/T50051), it mentions a similiar (?) bug was already resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the bug report you show has been resolved, it hasn't been included in a blender release. You will need a [recent daily build](https://builder.blender.org/download/) (after nov 2016) or [build your own from source](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender) to get that bug fix.

Note that the bug fix won't help, the solution to stop crashing was to disable grease pencil display in the VSE preview renders. I expect your solution will be to do an OpenGL render from the 3dview and then add the files to the VSE.